# Loading web page in Swing

Tags: swing

I want to show a website in swing Component(s) which is to be displayed exactly as how the browser display a website...!!! is it possible????

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use Swing, but not directly. You should be using Applets to display in a web page. However hard you try to improve the UI to make it look like a normal web page, the swingyness will still be shown. So, the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: I believe he wasn't asking, how to display Swing in webpage, but how to display webpage in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100%.

But JEditorPane supports some of HTML.

See [simple swing browser](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html)